# Adding Password to Passwordless PFX Using openssl

Tags: ssl, openssl, pem

When exporting a PFX from an Azure Key Vault, the PFX is exported with no password (or it might be with an empty password).

I need to use openssl to add a password to the PFX file. From reading various sites, I need to extract the key and crt files and then re-combine them into one file but this time with a password. However, every attempt to read the passwordless PFX file results in an error.

```
140462554078016:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag:crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:1149:
140462554078016:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_item_embed_d2i:nested asn1 error:crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:309:Type=PKCS12
```

I have tried the following variants and have included the error:

```
X:\Temp>openssl pkcs12 -in 443.pfx -nocerts -out 443.key
F8CB0000:error:068000A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag:crypto\asn1\tasn_dec.c:1188:
F8CB0000:error:0688010A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_item_embed_d2i:nested asn1 error:crypto\asn1\tasn_dec.c:349:Type=PKCS12

X:\Temp>openssl pkcs12 -in 443.pfx -out 443.key -passout pass: -passin pass:""
58860000:error:068000A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag:crypto\asn1\tasn_dec.c:1188:
58860000:error:0688010A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_item_embed_d2i:nested asn1 error:crypto\asn1\tasn_dec.c:349:Type=PKCS12

X:\Temp>openssl pkcs12 -in 443.pfx -out 443.key -passin pass:""
FCAA0000:error:068000A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag:crypto\asn1\tasn_dec.c:1188:
FCAA0000:error:0688010A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_item_embed_d2i:nested asn1 error:crypto\asn1\tasn_dec.c:349:Type=PKCS12

X:\Temp>openssl pkcs12 -in 443.pfx -out 443.key -passin pass:
40A90000:error:068000A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag:crypto\asn1\tasn_dec.c:1188:
40A90000:error:0688010A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_item_embed_d2i:nested asn1 error:crypto\asn1\tasn_dec.c:349:Type=PKCS12

X:\Temp>openssl pkcs12 -in 443.pfx -out 443.key -passin
pkcs12: Option -passin needs a value
pkcs12: Use -help for summary.

X:\Temp>openssl pkcs12 -in 443.pfx -out 443.key -passin pass:abc
58B50000:error:068000A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag:crypto\asn1\tasn_dec.c:1188:
58B50000:error:0688010A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_item_embed_d2i:nested asn1 error:crypto\asn1\tasn_dec.c:349:Type=PKCS12

X:\Temp>openssl pkcs12 -in 443.pfx -out 443.key -nodes
80940000:error:068000A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag:crypto\asn1\tasn_dec.c:1188:
80940000:error:0688010A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_item_embed_d2i:nested asn1 error:crypto\asn1\tasn_dec.c:349:Type=PKCS12
```

The PFX itself starts with

```
MIINhgIBAzCCDUIGCSqGSIb3DQEHAaC
```

and ends with

```
rMdLz4AGINAgIH0A==
```

I can sucessfully import the PFX into Windows (at the Password prompt I just press return and it imports the PFX).

What are are the openssl commands to extract the key and crt files?

Comment: *"I have tried a number of variants,"* - which says absolutely nothing what exactly you did. Please provide the specific command and the specific result for all the variants you've tried.

Comment: Thank you. I have added the extra commands. I do hope that it gives you the additional information you need to help. Many thanks.

Comment: A real PFX file is a binary file. It should not start with "MIINhgIBAzCCDUIGCSqGSIb3DQEHAaC..." - that's the base64 encoded file instead. You need to decode it from base64 to binary first - for example with "openssl base64"

Comment: Oh OK. So base 64 is not a legal format for PFX files? That's weird because I always thought that PFX was a Microsoft format and as it is a  Microsoft command that creates it, I just assumed they'd create a format that it legal as it's their format. I'll experiment with converting it from base64.